# Unable to extract a desired portion of text and discard the rest out of some elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I've used a selector within my python code to get `Soccer: Next To Play` out of some `html elements`. It works fine when I use a `for loop` and `.extract()` the unwanted portion. However, is there any better way to get the aforesaid text out of the elements other than what I have done below or at least to do the same with a one-liner expression.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content='''
  <div class="page-title-new">
   <h1>
    Soccer: Next To Play
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="race-large ng-hide" ng-show="vm.hasRaceNumber()">
     RACE
    </span>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="race-small ng-hide" ng-show="vm.hasRaceNumber()">
     R
    </span>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-hide" ng-show="vm.hasRaceNumber()">
    </span>
   </h1>
   <div aria-hidden="true" class="page-info-new ng-hide" ng-show="vm.hasEventDetailItems()">
    <!-- -->
   </div>
  </div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".page-title-new h1"):
    for elem in item.select("span"):elem.extract()
    print(item.text.strip())

# items = [item.text for item in soup.select(".page-title-new h1")] #what to do to finish it as a one-liner
# print(items)
```

With the loop what I get (this is what I wish to get without a loop or a one-liner code):

```
Soccer: Next To Play
```

Without the loop what I get:

```
Soccer: Next To Play RACE R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `soup.select_one()` method (to find only the 1st tag that matches the CSS selector):

```
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
result = soup.select_one(".page-title-new > h1").contents[0].strip()

print(result)
```

The output:

```
Soccer: Next To Play
```

Comment: You are such a gem @RomanPerekhrest. It worked just perfect. Could you provide me with any link to the usage of `contents` so that I can learn a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: @Topto, you're welcome. See the link https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children